# What is the timeout duration for acknowledge packets to arrive?

Tags: tftp

I'm trying to implement Trivial File Transfer Protocol *(RFC 1350)* in C++. After sending a request, how long should I wait for an acknowledge to arrive? Is there a standard for it?